# Using bcrypt-ruby to validate hashed passwords using version $2y

Tags: php, ruby, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

We're in a bit of a bind where we need to use Ruby to auth users against an existing db of users. The user's passwords were all generated using password_compat PHP library. All the hashed passwords start with $2y.

I've been using bcrypt-ruby to try and authenticate the users and I haven't found any success.

```
#This user's password is "password"
irb(main):041:0> g = BCrypt::Password.new("$2y$10$jD.PlMQwFSYSdu4imy8oCOdqKFq/FDlW./x9cMxoUmcLgdvKCDNd6")
=> "$2y$10$jD.PlMQwFSYSdu4imy8oCOdqKFq/FDlW./x9cMxoUmcLgdvKCDNd6"
irb(main):042:0> g == "password"
=> false
irb(main):044:0> g.version
=> "2y"
irb(main):045:0> g.cost
=> 10
irb(main):046:0> g.salt
=> "$2y$10$jD.PlMQwFSYSdu4imy8oCO"
irb(main):047:0> g.hash
=> -219334950017117414
```

I'm not very experienced with bcrypt or encryption in general. Can bcrypt-ruby handle $2y? I looked through the source and I don't think it can. Is this the fault of the underlying OS (I'm using OS X)?

Comment: There's an open pull request right now to include 2y:
https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/80

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, bcrypt-ruby can handle passwords hashed with `2y`. You just need to replace the `2y` by `2a`:

```
irb(main):002:0> BCrypt::Password.new("$2a$10$jD.PlMQwFSYSdu4imy8oCOdqKFq/FDlW./x9cMxoUmcLgdvKCDNd6") == "password"
=> true
```

This is necessary as bcrypt-ruby seems to follow [Solar Designer’s first suggestion to introduce just `2x` for a backward-compatible support for the “sign extension bug”](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/06/20/6):

> […] I am considering keeping support
>   for the broken hashes under another prefix - say, "$2x$" (where the "x"
>   would stand for "sign eXtension bug") instead of the usual "$2a$".

Later [he proposed to also introduce the `2y` prefix](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/06/21/16) for a better distinction between the three versions:

> One idea is to allocate **yet another prefix, which will mean the same
>   thing as 2a**, but "certified" as passing a certain specific test suite
>   (which will include 8-bit chars).  So we'll have:
>
> 2a - unknown correctness (may be correct, may be buggy)
>   2x - sign extension bug
>   2y - definitely correct
>
> Newly set/changed passwords will be getting the new prefix.

[PHP supports `2a`, `2x`, and `2y`](http://php.net/security/crypt_blowfish) while [bcrypt-ruby supports only `2a`, and `2x`](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blame/master/ext/mri/crypt_blowfish.c#L591). But if you know your implementation doesn’t have the “sign extension bug”, you can just replace `2y` by `2a`, as `2y` means the same thing as `2a`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. `$2y$` was introduced at PHP 5.3.7:  http://php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php